# Is it possible to add "any letter" to a string?

Tags: python

I am parsing a database and extracting entries to a new database. For this I use keywords which should and keywords which should not be included. For a keyword I want excluded, it should be "-anyletter-fv", I wonder if -anyletter- is possible to program. If there is no letter, a space, a comma, or anything but a letter, I don't want to exclude it, only if there is specifically a letter in front of it.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, but it's possible you could use a *regular expression* - see [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you try to exclude those cases in which your keyword starts with some letter.
Use library re for it (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
print(re.match("^\w.*", " keyword"))
```

will return a match object if a pattern that you look for is found, otherwise None.
You can use it for if-expressions.
the "^" marks the beginning of the sequence, "\w" matches all [a-zA-Z0-9], while ".*" matches all other sequences of varying length. 
Therefore you get matches for keywords that do not start with ascii character.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant, thank you for your help!